# Ruby on Rails - Pass selected checkboxes values from popup to main form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am a newbie on RoR and would be grateful if you could help me out with this problem.

In my rails application, I have my main form 'Submission'. Clicking on a link displays a popup containing a list of publications. User can select several publications using the checkbox, then  he clicks on a button/link and the popup gets closed and the selected publications id are displayed in my main form.

Here is the code for the publication popup:

```
<% @publications.each do |publication| %>
    <p><%= check_box_tag "submission[publication_ids][]", publication.ID %></p>
    <p><%=h publication.name %></p>
    <p><%=h publication.desc %></p>
    <p><%=h publication.author %></p>
<% end %>
```

I would like to pass the selected publication_ids to my main form.

Thanks a lot for helping me out with this

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to do this with JavaScript. The most straightforward method is to manipulate the parent document using something like jQuery to populate a hidden field on the main form. This is available through `window.parent` for the pop-up if both it and the parent page are hosted on the same site.